# How to make a pear shaped setting for a stone

Tags: modeling

I found this ring online and I really want to build it in Blender.

I got the basic shape and the little diamond on top but I cannot manage to make the setting for the green pear shaped stone. :( I also tried taking the outer edge of the stone and extruding it but I cannot manage with those prongs.

If you have any advice please let me know :D I'm sure it would help me allot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YasUu.jpg)[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRNWH.jpg)

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. What do you have done so far?

Answer (score 2):

@R.M's answer is good for the stone.  For the setting, here's an approach.

[image: ring setting]

[image: setting with stone]

In *Edit Mode*, select a horizontal edge loop of that stone (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>), e.g. the bottom edge.

Duplicate it (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), then split it into a new object (P).

Go into *Object Mode*, select that new object, and convert it into a curve (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Convert to Curve from Mesh/Text*).

In Edit mode, in the Curve Data tab, set a bevel.  Under *Fill* in the Shape section, chose Full.  Under *Bevel* in the *Geometry* section, set a depth (e.g. .05) and a resolution (e.g. 2) you like.

Now go back into Object mode.  You can scale the curve along the Z axis to make it more "band" like (or do this after you've converted to mesh).  Next, convert the curve back into a mesh.  You now have a band you can further edit and duplicate to make the top part of the setting.  You might want to give it a subsurf.

To make the vertical prongs, go through a similar process.  Working with the gem object in *Edit Mode*, select three vertical edges that are in the positions you want, duplicate them, split into a new object.  Convert the new object to a curve, bevel it, then convert to mesh.

You will need to edit these posts to make the tips bend inwards and to fill the caps, that will need to be done with reference to the gem object so they touch appropriately.  Hopefully this part is something you can do without a step by step.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, basically I haven't done anything regarding the two stones. I just had too many problems, I just need the setting for it. 

Thank you so much @risingfall! :D It's actually a genius method, I wouldn't have thought of turning it into a curve...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would create the basic shape:

Create a cylinder:
[image: Cylinder]

Select a side edge. Enable proportional editin with falloff mode `Sharp`. Move the edge to get this:
[image: Drag edge]

Select the top face. Bevel it (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) to get this:
[image: bevel]

Now, we need to add that triangular look. To do this, `Poke` the faces (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>), and set a small `Poke offset`:
[image: model]

Here's my result (I used a simple glass shader):
[image: Render]

Possible improvements:

- You could create some embellishments on the sides to make them more detailed
- The top face could have some "triangulation", too
- You could make the shader more accurate by researching the properties of the stone you want to emulate (like the IOR and exact color). A volume absorption shader also would make it more accurate.

Comment: Thank you! But I just ended up using the jewelcraft add-on for the stone, since I couldn't make it as a real stone would look like using this method.